# Vue omitting images and assets in production build

Tags: image, apache, vue.js, production-environment

Using Vue's default scripts:

```
"scripts": {
"serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
"build": "vue-cli-service build"
```

},

I run "npm run build" it produces the production build in the "dist" directory however in the end it says:

> Images and other types of assets were omitted.

I honestly don't understand what to do include them. I don't want to make a specific folder for images and upload so my web server can serve it. Vue should handle the files in its src/assets folder itself.

So far I have found a solution while googling which says to include:

```
NODE_ENV = PRODUCTION
```

But it doesn't work either.

Any clues how to get this fixed? I cannot launch a website without including its logo.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that message just means that they are omitted from the file listing displayed in the console during the build.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. They are omitted from build. My page is "broken" if I use `npm run build` and then serve it through DJango.

Doing `npm run serve` it will produce the right files in the django's static folders, and then, serving it from django (w npm server stopped) will work.